# Python open(x, 'w') not creating a new text file

Tags: python

whatever opening mode I try to use, it throws out this error:

```
    keylog = open(keydump, mode = 'w')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'keylog 2014/02/08-08/54/18.txt'
```

where

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d-%H/%M/%S')
keydump = ''.join(['keylog ', str(now), '.txt'])
```

Comment: Do you really want to create this directory tree `keylog 2014/02/08-08/54/`

Comment: its the '/'s in the filename, i can be very dumb sometimes. thanks!

Comment: Other characters can also cause problems, like colons, depending on your operating system.

Answer (score 4):

You're putting `/` in your filename when your system uses that as a path separator. If `/` is the path separator, it will try to create a file in a path that probably doesn't exist, hence your error.

In other words,

```
 keylog 2014/02/08-08/54/18.txt
```

is the file `18.txt` in the `keylog 2014/02/08-08/54` directory.

Comment: Even if your system uses backslashes as path separators, Python will still interpret forward slashes as path separators. Slashes aren't allowed within filenames on any system.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest replace `'/'` with `'_'` in the time representation:

```
keydump = ''.join(['keylog_', str(now).replace('/', '_'), '.txt'])
```